# datepicker reads month as date in dd/mm/yy format

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, datepicker

I am using the Jquery datepicker in jqgrid but the datepicker reads month as date in dd/mm/yy format.
What I mean is, when a user selects the date, the date is shown correclt in the dd/mm/yy format but the date passed to the structs action date setter method is in a Date object based on the mm/dd/yy format.

See below my code:

```
       <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <!--   Overide css styling to ensure that calendar image is inline with text box -->
    <style type="text/css">.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input > input,
                            .ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input > select,
                            .ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input > img {vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block;}
    </style>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Trucks Overview</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery().ready(function () {
        var grid = jQuery("#truck_grid");
        var orderGridDialog = $('#truck_grid_dialog');  
        var gridData;

        getUniqueNames = function(columnName) {
            var texts = grid.jqGrid('getCol', columnName, false);
            var uniqueTexts = [], textsLength = texts.length, text, i, textsMap = {}; 
            for (i=0;i<textsLength;i++) {
                text = texts[i];
                if (text != undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
                    // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
                    textsMap[text] = true;
                    uniqueTexts.push(text);
                }
            }
            return uniqueTexts;
        };
        buildSearchSelect = function(uniqueNames) {
            var values=":All";
            $.each (uniqueNames, function() {
                values += ";" + this + ":" + this;
            });
            return values;
        };
        setSearchSelect = function(columnName) {
            grid.jqGrid('setColProp', columnName,
                        {   stype: 'select',
                            searchoptions: {
                                value:buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames(columnName)),
                                sopt:['eq']
                            }
                        }
            );
        };

        var initDateWithButton = function (elem) {
            if (/^\d+%$/.test(elem.style.width)) {
                // remove % from the searching toolbar
                elem.style.width = '';
            }
            // to be able to use 'showOn' option of datepicker in advance searching dialog
            // or in the editing we have to use setTimeout
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                    showOn: 'button',
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,     
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
                    buttonText: "Select date",
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                        inst.input.focus();
                        if (typeof (inst.id) === "string" && inst.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                             $(inst.id).val(dateText);
                             grid[0].triggerToolbar();
                        }
                        else {
                            // to refresh the filter
                            $(inst).trigger("change");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 100);
        };

        grid.jqGrid({
            url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getTrucksJSONAction',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Truck ID', 'Status', 'Carrier Code', 'Date Created', 'Date Closed', 'T1 Status', 'Truck Arrived'],
            colModel: [
                {name: 'truckId', key:true, index: 'truckId', align: 'center', width: 100},
                {name: 'status', index: 'status', align: 'center', width: 100},
                {name: 'carrierName', index: 'carrierName', align: 'center', width: 100},
                {name: 'createdDate', index: 'createdDate', align: 'center', width: 100},
                {name: 'closedDate',  index: 'closedDate', align: 'center', width: 100},
                {name: 't1Status', sortable: false, align: 'center', width: 100, fixed: true,
                    formatter: function (celvalue) {
                        return celvalue ?
                            "<img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/q/j/I/0/8/d/green-circle-icon-md.png' alt='green light' style='width:15px;height:15px'/>" :
                            "<img src='http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/circle-xxl.png' alt='red light' style='width:10px;height:10px'/>";
                    }} ,
                {name: 'truckArrived', sortable: false, align: 'center', width: 100, fixed: true,
                        formatter: function (celvalue) {
                            return celvalue ?
                                "<img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/q/j/I/0/8/d/green-circle-icon-md.png' alt='green light' style='width:15px;height:15px'/>" :
                                "<img src='http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/red/circle-xxl.png' alt='red light' style='width:10px;height:10px'/>";
                        }}    
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            height: 300,
            autoheight: true,
            autowidth: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: jQuery('#truck_grid_pager'),
            sortname: 'truckId',
            sortorder: "desc",
            jsonReader: {
                root: "records",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "rows",
                repeatitems: false
            },
            viewrecords: true,
            altRows: false,
            gridview: true,
            hidegrid: false,
            multiselect:true,
            recordtext: '',
            emptyrecords: 'No Trucks',
            forceFit: true,
            caption: "Trucks Overview",
            loadComplete: function() { 
                // Reload the grid after changing paginattion
                var allRecords = grid.getGridParam('lastpage') * grid.getGridParam('records');
                grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { 
                    recordtext: allRecords + ' Trucks(s) Found. Displaying {0} to {1}'});   
                $(this).trigger("reloadGrid");
                async: false,
                setSearchSelect('status');
                setSearchSelect('carrierName');
                grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'truckId', {
                    searchoptions : {
                        sopt : [ 'bw' ],
                        dataInit : function(elem) {
                           $(elem).autocomplete({
                              source : getUniqueNames('truckId'),
                              delay : 0,
                              minLength : 0
                           });
                       }
                    }
                });   
                grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'createdDate', {
                    sorttype: 'date', editable: true,
                        editoptions: { dataInit: initDateWithButton, size: 8 },
                        searchoptions: {
                            sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
                            dataInit: initDateWithButton
                        }
                });   
                gridData = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
                grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autoSearch: true});
            },
        }).navGrid('#truck_grid_pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true})
        .navButtonAdd('#truck_grid_pager', {caption:"Truck Arrived", buttonicon:"ui-icon-flag",  position:"first", title:"Truck Arrived",
            onClickButton: function(){ 
                var i;
                var data = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
                var selRowIds = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (selRowIds.indexOf(data[i].truckId) > -1) {
                        data[i].truckArrived = true;
                    }
                }
                grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
             }
        })
        .navButtonAdd('#truck_grid_pager', {caption:"Ship Confirm", buttonicon:"ui-icon-circle-check",  position:"first", title:"Ship Confirm",
            onClickButton: function(){ 
             alert("Ship has been confirmed");}
        });

        orderGridDialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 1000,
            height: 400,
            draggable: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 500
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 250
            },
            close: function(event, ui){
                orderGridDialog.text('Loading Grid...');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="truck_grid"></table>
<div id="truck_grid_pager"></div>
<div id="truck_grid_dialog" title="Orders Overview">Loading...</div>
</body>
</html>


The problem happens in the last section of the code, namely:

        .navButtonAdd('#truck_grid_pager', {caption:"Truck Arrived", buttonicon:"ui-icon-flag",  position:"first", title:"Truck Arrived",
            onClickButton: function(){ 
                var i;
                var data = grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "data");
                var selRowIds = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (selRowIds.indexOf(data[i].truckId) > -1) {
                        data[i].truckArrived = true;
                    }
                }
                grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
             }
        })
```

How can I ensure that the dd/mm/yy date format is returned to the struts action date setter?

Comment: It's code fragment only which uses jQuery UI Datepicker only. It's important to know full column definition.

Comment: @Oleg: do you mean I should move the following  grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'createdDate', {...} code from loadComplete function to the colModel section ?

Comment: Yes. Moreover one should use `formatter: 'date'`. Using `srcformat` and `newformat` of `formatoptions` one specify the input format of data and the displayed format of date.

Comment: Moreover the code have some common JavaScript problems. For example you defines functions `getUniqueNames`, `buildSearchSelect` and some other as **global** (as properties of global `window` object). It's bad. You should include `var` before every such definition to fix the problem. I recommend you to use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) (or both) to validate your code. Choosing corresponding options you can detect real problems in your code like

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for the correction and coaching. I will only become better as I implement your tips.

Comment: You are welcome! Is the main problem with the dates solved now?

Comment: @Oleg: I'm migrating from my old Eclipse to Luna so I've not yet covered that part. Will inform you about my progress later

Comment: @Oleg: I ,moved the properties from loadComplete to colModel and I used  formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d', newformat: 'd-m-Y'}. It works well now. Many thanks